# python : error handling Ordered dict with unicode data

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, unicode, pymongo

My script migrates data from MySQL to mongodb. It runs perfectly well when there are no unicode columns included. But throws me below error when `OrgLanguages` column is added.

```
    mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(odbcArray)
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 711, in insert_many
    blk.execute(self.write_concern.document)
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 493, in execute
    return self.execute_command(sock_info, generator, write_concern)
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 319, in execute_command
    run.ops, True, self.collection.codec_options, bwc)
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: 'Portugu\xeas do Brasil, ?????, English, Deutsch, Espa\xf1ol latinoamericano, Polish'
```

My code:

```
import MySQLdb, MySQLdb.cursors, sys, pymongo, collections

odbcArray=[]
mongoConStr = '192.168.10.107:36006'
sqlConnect = MySQLdb.connect(host = "54.175.170.187", user = "testuser", passwd = "testuser", db = "testdb", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
mongoConnect = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoConStr)

sqlCur = sqlConnect.cursor()
sqlCur.execute("SELECT ID,OrgID,OrgLanguages,APILoginID,TransactionKey,SMTPSpeed,TimeZoneName,IsVideoWatched FROM organizations")

dbo = mongoConnect.eaedw.mysqlData
tuples = sqlCur.fetchall()

for tuple in tuples:
    odbcArray.append(collections.OrderedDict(tuple))

mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(odbcArray)

sqlCur.close()
mongoConnect.close()
sqlConnect.close()
sys.exit()
```

Above script migraates data perfectly when tried without `OrgLanguages` column in the SELECT query.
To overcome this, I have tried to use the `OrderedDict()` in another way but gives me a different type of error
Changed Code:

```
for tuple in tuples:
    doc = collections.OrderedDict()
    doc['oid'] = tuple.OrgID
    doc['APILoginID'] = tuple.APILoginID
    doc['lang'] = unicode(tuple.OrgLanguages)
    odbcArray.append(doc)
mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(odbcArray)
```

Error Received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymsql.py", line 19, in <module>
    doc['oid'] = tuple.OrgID
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'OrgID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL connection is returning characters in a different encoding than UTF-8, which is the encoding that all BSON strings must be in. Try your original code but pass `charset='utf8'` to `MySQLdb.connect`.